# Pharmaceutical Planet?

Tags: story-identification

Looking for book title.  It was a bit like Midworld perhaps, but I don't think that's it. It's a rainforest world being exploited by a pharmaceutical company. People come from offworld to be drug test volunteers. There's an indigenous human-like race that live in symbiosis with the plants. Some of the volunteers head into the jungle and "go native", becoming completely subsumed by the plants. In one scene the main characters come upon a man sitting lotus position in the jungle, unmoving and wasting away.

Comment: If not for the fact that it's a whole world and the pharmaceutical company, this could be the country Nyissa from the Belgariad series.

Comment: As it is, sounds like an Ursula le Guin story.

Comment: How many main characters are there? Can you describe anything about them?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like Norman Spinrad's [Child Of Fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_of_Fortune).  The main character goes to the planet Belshazaar and seeks employment as a paid test subject for the psychotropic chemicals which are the planet's main export.  She does later go into the jungle of plants from which these compounds are derived and spends some time in a trancelike state as a result of exposure to them.

Here is an extract regarding people wasting away while under the influence of the chemicals:

> "the spirit animating the withering body evinced a preparation to withdraw from further worldly discourse....His spirit had long since departed to the untrammeled contemplation of regions within.  No effort of ours could conjure it to speak again."

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks!!!